# Connecting QGIS to query on MS Access database?

Tags: qgis, ms-access

Is there a method to connect to an MS Access database file (.mdb) using QGIS?

In particular I need to connect to a query in it.

The database does not have spatial data.

Answer (score 11):

It's possible to connect via ODBC.

- In windows, start the ODBC Administrator and define your Datasource (Microsoft Access Driver).
- In QGIS go to Layer/Add Layer/Vector Layer/database: Type=ODBC.
- Set up a new Connection. Host should be "localhost" if your database
  is local on your machine. Database Name is the same name you defined before in the ODBC Administrator.

Answer (score 3):

... or directly with MS Access Forms ...

There is a simple way:

You are able to define an action for each layer (see: Layerproperties).
There you can input a Python script.

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch

dbname ="dbname.mdb"

dbForm = "frmname"

filter ='id= "[% "ID" %]"'

a=Dispatch("Access.Application")

a.Visible=True

objDB = a.CurrentDb()
            
if objDB is None:

    a.OpenCurrentDatabase(dbname,True)

a.DoCmd.OpenForm(dbForm)

a.forms(dbForm).Filter = filter

a.forms(dbForm).FilterOn = True
```