# How to join a specific cell in excel to the corresponding polygons in QGIS/MapInfo

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mapinfo, excel, hyperlink

I would like to be able to create an excel database that has hyperlinks into a QGIS or MapInfo table so that if I clicked within the cell (which is linked to a particular polygon) I would be taken directly to the polygon on MapInfo/QGIS (I am saying either as I currently work on both platforms). The Site ID  in excel would match the cell to the polygon.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't join or relate the excel sheet/csv to the polygon in QGIS ?

Comment: What version of MapInfo Pro are you using?

Comment: Hi Peter, I am using MapInfo 15.2,

Comment: Hi GIS kid, I do not need to join data to the polygon in QGIS. Instead, I would like to be able to view the polygon on QGIS/MapInfo by simply clicking in a cell in Excel that corresponds to a particular polygon through a matching site ID. I will have a series of attribute data for all polygons within an excel spreadsheet and it would be useful to have that linked to the GIS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with MapInfo so this is an ArcGIS/QGIS answer (same theory applies). I don't think you can dynamically link an excel sheet to popup an QGIS instance with the correct polygon selected. What is the use case for this, exactly? Here is a thorough overview of using [Excel with ArcGIS.](https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0104/files/excel.pdf)

It would make more sense (imo) to [add the excel sheet](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html) as a table or dbf and then either join or relate it to the polygon. You could examine the table in QGIS and then "Zoom to Location" once a polygon is selected.

If you want to connect your existing Access database to QGIS here are the instructions [Connecting to a Microsoft Access Database in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145083/connecting-qgis-to-query-on-ms-access-database), then you can alter your tables in access and link them up in the GIS but I still don't think it would do what you're looking for.

If you're familiar with programming and VBA there might be a way to create a custom script that could potentially do this for you, this forum has some [code for opening a pdf from a clicked cell in excel.](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=154851). Aside from building your own solution with VBA, I don't think there's an out of the box way to do what you're asking.